# The behavior of dictionary and list

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have list from django

```
>>> post = Post.objects.all()
>>> post
[<Post: one>, <Post: two>, <Post: three>, <Post: four>]
```

and when I use for loop to put objects to dictionary and list

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = {}
>>> for p in post:
...  b[post.pub_date.year] = post.pub_date.month
...  a.append(b)
```

and result list show:

```
>>> a 
[{2016: 4, 2015: 8}, {2016: 4, 2015: 8}, {2016: 4, 2015: 8}, {2016: 4, 2015: 
8}]
```

every dictionary all the same in list

but this code will work for what I want:

```
>>> for p in post:
...  a.append({p.pub_date.year:p.pub_date.month})
```

and result is:

```
>>> a
[{2016: 5}, {2016: 4}, {2015: 10}, {2015: 8}]
```

so the question is what's happening in dictionary?
I don't understand this behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem is where you've defined the `b` dictionary. You've done it before the loop, but needed to do it inside:

```
for p in post:
    b = {}
    b[p.pub_date.year] = p.pub_date.month
    a.append(b)
```

Or, with a *list comprehension*:

```
 a = [{p.pub_date.year: p.pub_date.month} for p in post]
```

Comment: so if dictionary is outside the loop, b dictionary will replace original dictionary,and if in the loop will create new b dictionary so the list will not be the same dictionary?

Comment: @martinwang yeah, you are basically modifying the same dictionary over and over again if you define it outside of the loop. Thanks.